# Yarn test with docker inside github actions does not finish ever

Tags: docker, yarnpkg, github-actions

I've a react app that is build with docker. And now I've tests on it, but the step yarn test never finish inside a github action.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update && apk add jq
COPY . /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN yarn --silent
RUN yarn lint
RUN yarn test
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:alpine as nginx

RUN apk add --no-cache certbot
COPY nginx/renew /etc/periodic/daily/renew
RUN chmod +x /etc/periodic/daily/renew
RUN mkdir /var/lib/certbot

VOLUME /var/log/nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./env.sh .
COPY .env .

RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN chmod +x env.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

Before add the line run yarn test everuthing works fine running the build in gh action, but after this is what appears:

```
 Test Suites: 3 passed, 3 total
Tests:       10 passed, 10 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        15.335s
Ran all test suites.

Error: The operation was canceled.
```

And gets there for almost 6 hours and the github stops the job by himself.
Any idea?